# How to configure `train_and_evaluate` to also save the metric on training set into tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have the following code that trains a model on the iris data set and uses accuracy as the metric to evaluate the model:

```
# This is based on the complete code for the following blogpost:
# https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-tensorflow-datasets.html


import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import Experiment, RunConfig
from urllib.request import urlopen
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import RunConfig

()

PATH = "./tf_dataset_and_estimator_apis"

# Fetch and store Training and Test dataset files
PATH_DATASET = PATH + os.sep + "dataset"
FILE_TRAIN = PATH_DATASET + os.sep + "iris_training.csv"
FILE_TEST = PATH_DATASET + os.sep + "iris_test.csv"
URL_TRAIN = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv"
URL_TEST = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv"


def downloadDataset(url, file):
    if not os.path.exists(PATH_DATASET):
        os.makedirs(PATH_DATASET)
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        data = urlopen(url).read()
        with open(file, "wb") as f:
            f.write(data)
            f.close()


downloadDataset(URL_TRAIN, FILE_TRAIN)
downloadDataset(URL_TEST, FILE_TEST)

# The CSV features in our training & test data
feature_names = [
    'SepalLength',
    'SepalWidth',
    'PetalLength',
    'PetalWidth']


# Create an input function reading a file using the Dataset API
# Then provide the results to the Estimator API


def my_input_fn(file_path, perform_shuffle=False, repeat_count=1):
    def decode_csv(line):
        parsed_line = tf.decode_csv(line, [[0.], [0.], [0.], [0.], [0]])
        label = parsed_line[-1:]  # Last element is the label
        del parsed_line[-1]  # Delete last element
        features = parsed_line  # Everything but last elements are the features
        d = dict(zip(feature_names, features)), label
        return d

    dataset = (tf.contrib.data.TextLineDataset(file_path)  # Read text file
               .skip(1)  # Skip header row
               .map(decode_csv))  # Transform each elem by applying decode_csv fn
    if perform_shuffle:
        # Randomizes input using a window of 256 elements (read into memory)
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=256)
    # dataset = dataset.repeat(repeat_count)  # Repeats dataset this # times
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(32)  # Batch size to use
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    batch_features, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()
    return batch_features, batch_labels


next_batch = my_input_fn(FILE_TRAIN, True)  # Will return 32 random elements

# Create the feature_columns, which specifies the input to our model
# All our input features are numeric, so use numeric_column for each one
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in feature_names]

# Create a deep neural network regression classifier
# Use the DNNClassifier pre-made estimator
config = RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=50, save_summary_steps=50)
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,  # The input features to our model
    hidden_units=[10, 10],  # Two layers, each with 10 neurons
    n_classes=3,
    model_dir=PATH + '/model_dir',
    config=config)  # Path to where checkpoints etc are stored

experiment = Experiment(
    estimator=classifier,
    train_input_fn=lambda: my_input_fn(FILE_TRAIN, True, 8),
    eval_input_fn=lambda: my_input_fn(FILE_TEST, False, 4),
    eval_metrics=None,
    train_steps=1000,
    min_eval_frequency=50,
    eval_delay_secs=0
)

experiment.train_and_evaluate()
```

This is the tensorboard result:

[image]

Is there a way to configure the Experiment or the DNNClassifier class so that the accuracy metric is also computed on the training set and displayed in tensorboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.summary.scalar to display training accuracy in tensorboard, for example:

```
accuracy = tf.metrics.mean(some_tensor)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
   tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])
```

Comment: where should I insert the snippet you gave into my code?

Comment: I think you should upgrade from using the packages tensorflow.contrib.learn such as Experiment, and use Estimators or Keras. These packages will be deprecated soon. Then it will make more sense where to insert his snipped or when to use tf.summary.scalar in general.